# G++/GCC Compiler is giving undefined reference error when optiomzation is turned off

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, linker

I have a HUGE C++ program which compiles fine with -O3 optimization but gives a "undefined reference to strings_array_multilevel variable" error, when compiled with -g option (-O3 is removed).

I have reduced the testcase somewhat. If you have encountered a similar error, let me know how you fixed it. I have a library named libtest.so. The file test.c is compiled into a library using standard gcc commands. The thing to note is that header file test.h has an array declared as an extern (**strings_array_multilevel**)

```
const struct mystruct elem3 =  {
                        {30, 9, 26},
                        {
                            {
                                {9, 9},
                                {9, 9}
                            },
                            {
                                {9, 11},
                                {9, 11}
                            }
                        },
                        (char**)strings_array_multilevel
                    };
```

test.h : Please see here http://pastebin.com/rPULDeXk

```
include <stdio.h>

const int NUM_AIRORTS = 10;
const int NUM_REGIONS = 1024;

struct mystruct {
    int field1[3];
    int field2[2][2][2];
    char ** strings;
};

extern const char* strings_array_multilevel[NUM_AIRORTS][NUM_REGIONS];

const struct mystruct elem0 = {
                            {0,0,0},  
                            {
                                {
                                    {0,0},
                                    {0,0}
                                },
                                {
                                    {0,0},
                                    {0,0}
                                }
                            },
                            0
                        };

const struct mystruct elem1 = {
                        {30, 9, 26},
                        {
                            {
                                {9, 9},
                                {9, 9}
                            },
                            {
                                {9, 11},
                                {9, 11}
                            }
                        },
                        NULL
                    };

const struct mystruct elem2 = {
                       {0,0,0},  
                       {
                           {
                               {0,0},
                               {0,0}
                           },
                           {
                               {0,0},
                               {0,0}
                           }
                       },
                       NULL
                   };                    

const struct mystruct elem3 = {
                        {30, 9, 26},
                        {
                            {
                                {9, 9},
                                {9, 9}
                            },
                            {
                                {9, 11},
                                {9, 11}
                            }
                        },
                        (char**)strings_array_multilevel
                    };



int doStuff (int index1, int latency);
```

test.c : Please see here http://pastebin.com/GnSZAZUx

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "test.h"

const struct mystruct* mystructarray[4] = {&elem0, &elem1, &elem2, &elem3};

int doStuff (int index1, int index) {
    int retVal = 0;
    retVal = mystructarray[index1]->field1[index];
    return retVal;
}

const char* strings_array_multilevel[NUM_AIRORTS][NUM_REGIONS] =
{
    {
        "SJC", "SFO", "OAK"
    },
    {
        "NYC", "WP", "LGA", "PHY"
    }
};
```

Makefile :Please see here http://pastebin.com/y4LMg2SR

```
all:
        g++ -fpic -c test.c -o test.o
        g++ -shared -o libtest.so test.o

clean:
        rm test.o libtest.so
```

Now, when I include test.h in my a project and link it against libtest.so with option -g, I get following error

```
cat use_library.c 
#include <stdio.h> 
int main () { 
    printf ("hello world\n"); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Following works.

```
g++ -O3 use_library.c -L<original_directory> -ltest
```

The following fails

```
g++ -g use_library.c -L<original_directory> -ltest     


Undefined reference to  strings_array_multilevel
```

Please let me know if you can figure this out. Sorry, because of private nature of code, I cannot share it here.

Thanks

Comment: What happens when you compile with both `-g` and `-O3`?

Comment: yes "==" is a typo. Corrected it now.

Comment: @ChristopherCreutzig, When I use both, the error is not present. I used "nm" command/utility and verified that strings_array_multilevel is defined in exported library.

Comment: `-g` and `-O` are different options (`-g` is translated to `-g2`). `-g` is debug information, while `-O` is optimizations. They are not entangled, and you can build with `-O0 -g3` or `-O3 and -g2`. One does not affect the other. If you want maximum debug information, then use `-g3`. `-g3` includes symbolic defines.

Comment: Why do you compile with g++ and gcc? That will cause mangling differences on those names.

Comment: _"I have reduced the testcase somewhat."_ You still have a lot of code spread about various links to the internet. Reduce the testcase _completely_, and post a minimal, self-contained example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: _"Sorry, because of private nature of code, I cannot share it here."_ Irrelevant. Abstract away the sensitive details. Make the example generic. This should have been one of your first steps when attempting to resolve the problem yourself, and it would likely have led directly to a realisation.

Answer (score 0):

quite simple: if you enable optimization the compiler inlines the function. There is no need to link against the library function. If optimization is switched of, you need the function from the lib. Solution: Link with your library which contains the needed function! You have to add something like

```
g++    -g -O3 use_library.cpp -L<LIBDIR> -l<libname>
```

I believe your file `test` do not contain the needed function! Attention must be paid for name mangling in c++! If you link against a c library you have to include the header from the lib with `extern "C"` if there is no guard inside the library header.

As a hint: If you have so little files please give the full text here. It is not nice to follow external links for reading.

Comment: Hmm where do I start? Your `-l<libname>` is in the wrong place and won't do anything. Let's start there. :)

Comment: Start with extern "C" :-)

Comment: @Klaus, Thanks for the reply. As I have mentioned before, I used nm utility and checked the symbol is indeed present in the library. Note that none of the functions from library are being called in use_library.cpp but it is still giving an error. I also tried extern 'C' option, but it gave the same result.

Comment: @Klaus, Since code is 50+ lines, I thought it would be easier to follow external links. I posted it inline now Thanks –